# OpenGLES - Could not allocate a memory page for the adreno_pool_allocator

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have an app that is running a 2D animation of a candle with a flickering flame. This is made up of a rectangle with an image of a candlestick as a texture (512*512px, 158 KB), and a vector flame coloured in with a shader.

The application runs absolutely fine for an hour or so, and then exits. Whilst there is no error on the device, if you are debugging you (briefly) see:

```
10-13 16:05:46.420    8373-8418/org.projectcede.flame.app E/Adreno-SC﹕ <allocate:384>: Could not allocate a memory page for the adreno_pool_allocator.
10-13 16:05:46.420    8373-8418/org.projectcede.flame.app A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 8418 (Thread-262)
```

Based upon some testing (the frequency of...

```
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 536K, 14% free 9672K/11204K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
```

...in the debug log) I think it's the flickering flame rather than the texture.

I have tried Googling the error and have been through a few books, but I have absolutely no idea what to do about this.

I presume that it is a memory leak of some sort, and that it is probably down to me not deallocating something OpenGLES-side, but I have no idea what.

I have tried calling `GLES20.glDeleteProgram(mProgram);` after each draw, but that has no effect.

Any ideas would be gratefully received!

Here is the class to draw the flickering flame:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Creates a flickering leaf constructed from two bezier curves
 *
 * @author jonnyhuck
 * @version 0.1
 */
public class FlickeringFlame {

    // finals
    private static final Random r = new Random();
    private static final String A_POSITION = "aPosition";
    private static final String A_COLOR = "aColor";
    private static final String U_MATRIX = "uMVPMatrix";
    // vertex values
    private static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 2;
    private static final int COLOURS_PER_VERTEX = 4;
    private static final int COMPONENTS_PER_VERTEX = COORDS_PER_VERTEX + COLOURS_PER_VERTEX;
    private static final int VERTEX_STRIDE = COMPONENTS_PER_VERTEX * 4;
    // curve values
    private static final int VERTICES_PER_CURVE = 22;
    private static final int COORDS_PER_CURVE = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * VERTICES_PER_CURVE;
    // leaf values
    private static final int VERTICES_PER_LEAF = VERTICES_PER_CURVE * 2;
    private static final int COORDS_PER_LEAF = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * VERTICES_PER_LEAF;
    // centroid once, inner twice, mid twice, outer once...
    private static final ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(((VERTICES_PER_LEAF * 5) + 1) * VERTEX_STRIDE);
    // variables
    private static final String LOGTAG = "JONNY!";
    // shaders
    private static String vertexShaderCode;
    private static String fragmentShaderCode;
    private static int vertexShader;
    private static int fragmentShader;
    private float[] bezierCoords;
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private int mProgram;
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;
    private int aColorLocation;

    /**
     * Build the shaders
     */
    public FlickeringFlame(Context context) {

        // build and compile vertex shader
        vertexShaderCode = readTextFileFromResource(context,
                R.raw.vertex_shader);
        // vertexShaderCode = readTextFileFromResource(context, R.raw.test);
        vertexShader = MyRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                vertexShaderCode);
        // build and compile fragment shader
        fragmentShaderCode = readTextFileFromResource(context,
                R.raw.fragment_shader);
        fragmentShader = MyRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                fragmentShaderCode);
    }

    /**
     * Read a text file fro the resources (used to read in the vertex shader)
     *
     * @param context
     * @param resourceId
     * @return
     */
    public static String readTextFileFromResource(Context context,
                                                  int resourceId) {
        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(
                    resourceId);
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    inputStreamReader);
            String nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                body.append(nextLine);
                body.append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Could not open resource: " + resourceId, e);
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException nfe) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, nfe.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException("Resource not found: " + resourceId, nfe);
        }
        // Log.i(LOGTAG, body.toString());
        return body.toString();
    }

    /**
     * draw the object
     * <p/>
     * TODO: Throw exception if the mProgram does not link
     */
    public void draw(float[] mMVPMatrix) {

        // use the device hardware's native byte order
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        // build the OpenGL 'program'
        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram(); // create empty OpenGL ES Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader); // add vertex shader
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add fragment shader
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram); // creates OpenGL ES program executables
        int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(mProgram, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0); // 6
        if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Could not link program: ");
            Log.e(LOGTAG, GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(mProgram));
            GLES20.glDeleteProgram(mProgram);
        }
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram); // Add program to OpenGL environment

        // create the leaf shape
        bezierCoords = createFlame( //
//              0f, -0.25f, //
//              0.125f, -0.25f, //
//              0.05f, 0.15f, //
//              0f, 0.25f, //
//              // 0f, 0f); //this keeps it still
//              0.075f, 0.025f);
                0f, -0.13f, //
                0.07f, -0.08f, //
                0.025f, 0.08f, //
                0f, 0.13f, //
                // 0f, 0f); //this keeps it still
                0.038f, 0.013f);

        // create a floating point buffer
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();

        // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
        vertexBuffer.put(bezierCoords);

        // get handle to vertex shader's position data
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, A_POSITION);

        // get handle to fragment shader's colour data
        aColorLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, A_COLOR);

        // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, U_MATRIX);
        MyRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
        MyRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

        // Prepare the coordinate data
        vertexBuffer.position(0); // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_STRIDE, vertexBuffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Prepare the colour data
        vertexBuffer.position(COORDS_PER_VERTEX); // skip the coordinates - start reading at the start of the colours
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aColorLocation, COLOURS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_STRIDE, vertexBuffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aColorLocation);

        //enable transparency
        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        // Draw the 3 sections
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 1 + VERTICES_PER_LEAF); // INNER
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 2 + VERTICES_PER_LEAF, VERTICES_PER_LEAF * 2); // MIDDLE
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 2 + (3 * VERTICES_PER_LEAF), VERTICES_PER_LEAF * 2); // OUTER

        //disable transparency
        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }

    /**
     * Build a flame
     *
     * @return
     */
    private float[] createFlame(float p0x, float p0y, float p1x, float p1y,
                                float p2x, float p2y, float p3x, float p3y, float ctrlOffset,
                                float tipOffset) {

        /* INNER FLAME */

        // get the leaf shape
        float[] inner = createLeaf(p0x, p0y, p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, p3x, p3y,
                ctrlOffset * 0.6f, tipOffset * 0.3f);

        // create an array to take it and a centre point
//      float[] coords = new float[(COMPONENTS_PER_LEAF * COMPONENTS_PER_VERTEX)
//              + COMPONENTS_PER_VERTEX];
        float[] coords = new float[((VERTICES_PER_LEAF * 5) + 1) * COMPONENTS_PER_VERTEX];

        // load the screen centroid
        coords[0] = 0f; // x
        coords[1] = 0f; // y
        coords[2] = 0.15f; // r
        coords[3] = 0f; // g
        coords[4] = 0f; // b
        coords[5] = 1f; // a

        // load in the leaf, applying colours
        int j;
        for (int i = 0; i < inner.length; i += COORDS_PER_VERTEX) {

            // calculate next position
            j = (i / 2) * COMPONENTS_PER_VERTEX + COMPONENTS_PER_VERTEX;

            // populate array with coords and colour
            coords[j] = inner[i]; // x
            coords[j + 1] = inner[i + 1]; // y
            coords[j + 2] = 1f; // r
            coords[j + 3] = 0f; // g
            coords[j + 4] = 0f; // b
            coords[j + 5] = 1f; // a
        }

//      /* MID FLAME */
//
//      // build the mid section of the flame
        float multiplier = 3f;
        float[] mid = createLeaf(p0x, p0y, p1x * multiplier, p1y, p2x
                * multiplier, p2y * multiplier, p3x * multiplier, p3y
                * multiplier, ctrlOffset * 0.8f, tipOffset * 0.6f);

        int k;
        for (int i = 0; i < inner.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX; i++) {

            // calculate array positions
            j = (COMPONENTS_PER_VERTEX * VERTICES_PER_LEAF) + COMPONENTS_PER_VERTEX + (i * COMPONENTS_PER_VERTEX * 2);
            k = i * COORDS_PER_VERTEX;

            // populate mid
            coords[j] = mid[k]; // x
            coords[j + 1] = mid[k + 1]; // y
            coords[j + 2] = 1f; // r
            coords[j + 3] = 1f; // g
            coords[j + 4] = 0f; // b
            coords[j + 5] = 0.95f; // a

            // populate inner
            coords[j + 6] = inner[k]; // x
            coords[j + 7] = inner[k + 1]; // y
            coords[j + 8] = 1f; // r
            coords[j + 9] = 0f; // g
            coords[j + 10] = 0f; // b
            coords[j + 11] = 1f; // a
        }

        /* OUTER FLAME */

        // build the outer section of the flame
        multiplier = 4f;
        //(p0y - ctrlOffset just stops the mid from overlapping the outer at the base of the flame)
        float[] outer = createLeaf(p0x, p0y - ctrlOffset, p1x * multiplier, p1y, p2x
                * multiplier, p2y * multiplier, p3x * multiplier, p3y
                * multiplier, ctrlOffset, tipOffset);

        for (int i = 0; i < (inner.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX); i++) {

            // calculate array positions
            j = ((COMPONENTS_PER_VERTEX * VERTICES_PER_LEAF) * 3) + COMPONENTS_PER_VERTEX + (i * COMPONENTS_PER_VERTEX * 2);
            k = i * COORDS_PER_VERTEX;

            // populate outer
            coords[j] = outer[k]; // x
            coords[j + 1] = outer[k + 1]; // y
            coords[j + 2] = 1f; // r
            coords[j + 3] = 1f; // g
            coords[j + 4] = 0f; // b
            coords[j + 5] = 0f; // a

            // populate mid
            coords[j + 6] = mid[k]; // x
            coords[j + 7] = mid[k + 1]; // y
            coords[j + 8] = 1f; // r
            coords[j + 9] = 1f; // g
            coords[j + 10] = 0f; // b
            coords[j + 11] = 0.95f; // a
        }

//        String out = "";
//        for (int z = 0; z < coords.length; z++){
//            out += coords[z] + ", ";
//        }
//        Log.w(LOGTAG, out);
        return coords;
    }

    /**
     * Build the 'leaf' shape
     *
     * @return
     */
    private float[] createLeaf(float p0x, float p0y, float p1x, float p1y,
                               float p2x, float p2y, float p3x, float p3y, float ctrlOffset,
                               float tipOffset) {

        // get new top
        float[] flameTop = {p3x + rand(-ctrlOffset, ctrlOffset),
                p3y + rand(-ctrlOffset, ctrlOffset)};

        // load in the bezier curves
        final float[] left = create2DBezierCurve(p0x, //
                p0y, //
                p1x + rand(-ctrlOffset, ctrlOffset), //
                p1y + rand(-ctrlOffset, ctrlOffset), //
                p2x + rand(-ctrlOffset, ctrlOffset), //
                p2y + rand(-ctrlOffset, ctrlOffset), //
                flameTop[0], //
                flameTop[1]);
        final float[] right = create2DBezierCurve(flameTop[0], //
                flameTop[1], //
                p2x * -1f + rand(-ctrlOffset, ctrlOffset), //
                p2y + rand(-ctrlOffset, ctrlOffset), //
                p1x * -1f + rand(-ctrlOffset, ctrlOffset), //
                p1y + rand(-ctrlOffset, ctrlOffset), //
                p0x, //
                p0y);

        // load into output array & return
        float[] coords = new float[COORDS_PER_LEAF];
        for (int i = 0; i < COORDS_PER_CURVE; i++) {
            coords[i] = left[i];
            coords[i + COORDS_PER_CURVE] = right[i];
        }
        return coords;
    }

    /**
     * Create a 2D cubic bezier curve
     * <p/>
     * {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve}
     * p0
     * The start anchor point for the Bezier curve
     * p1
     * The first control point for the Bezier curve
     * p2
     * The second control point for the Bezier curve
     * p3
     * The end anchor point for the Bezier curve
     *
     * @return Float array of 3D coordinates for a Bezier Curve
     */
    private float[] create2DBezierCurve(float p0x, float p0y, float p1x,
                                        float p1y, float p2x, float p2y, float p3x, float p3y) {

        // loop through 11 points along the curve
        float t2;
        int t3;
        float[] coords = new float[COORDS_PER_CURVE];
        for (int t = 0; t < VERTICES_PER_CURVE; t++) {

            // scale t down
            t2 = t * (1f / (VERTICES_PER_CURVE - 1)); // value between 0-1
            t3 = t * 2; // the array position to write to

            // get coords along the curve for x & y
            coords[t3] = create1DBezierCurve(p0x, p1x, p2x, p3x, t2);
            coords[t3 + 1] = create1DBezierCurve(p0y, p1y, p2y, p3y, t2);
        }
        return coords;
    }

    /**
     * Create a 1D cubic bezier curve
     * <p/>
     * {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve}
     *
     * @param p0 The start anchor point for the Bezier curve
     * @param p1 The first control point for the Bezier curve
     * @param p2 The second control point for the Bezier curve
     * @param p3 The end anchor point for the Bezier curve
     * @param t  The distance along the curve on a scale of 0-1
     * @return
     */
    private float create1DBezierCurve(float p0, float p1, float p2, float p3,
                                      float t) {
        return (1 - t) * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * p0 + (3 * ((1 - t) * (1 - t))) * t
                * p1 + (3 * (1 - t)) * (t * t) * p2 + (t * t * t) * p3;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a random float between two specified values
     *
     * @param hi The upper limit of the random number range
     * @param lo The lower limit of the random number range
     * @return
     */
    private float rand(float hi, float lo) {
        return r.nextFloat() * (hi - lo) / 1 + lo;
    }
}
```

The vertex shader is:

```
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
attribute vec4 aPosition;
attribute vec4 aColor;
varying vec4 vColor;
void main() {
    vColor = aColor;
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;
}
```

The fragment shader is:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 vColor;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
```

Thankyou very much!

Comment: Is there a reason why you create everything from scratch on every draw -call?

Comment: Thanks for the question, the shape of the flame changes by a random amount every draw (making it flicker), though this is my first attempt at drawing in OpenGLES and it could well be that there's a more efficient way to do this? Are you thinking that I could do all the mProgram setup just once and then replace the coordinates at draw perhaps?

Comment: I believe it's more common to create i.e program and textures only once (if applicable). If you check GLSurfaceView.Renderer interface, there are three callbacks ; one for context/surface created, one for surface size changed and one for drawing. The surface created callback is handy for program creation since it will be called only when OpenGL context is created.

Comment: Thankyou - I'll take a look and see if it makes a difference, hopefully it will!

Comment: You would definitely have to delete the program if you create it on every draw call. But it's much better to create it only once. I figure you instantiate `FlickeringFlame` only once? I believe you lose some memory in its constructor because you're not closing the streams. But if that's a one time thing, it wouldn't explain the gradual memory leak.

Comment: Thanks - Yep, it is instantiated only once

Comment: @harism that seems to have worked! Thanks for the hint. Would you like to make it an answer?